# Disproportionate CPU usage

Tags: relays, dos

My new Raspberry Pi 3 relay was relaying 2 MBps using maybe 80% CPU for a few days. But suddenly, just today, it jumped to using 380% CPU, using almost all of each of the 4 cores to serve the same amount of data. I set the bandwidth limit to 1 MBps now and it's still using 200% CPU. I know Tor uses a lot of CPU, but isn't something wrong here?

For a while, just serving 2 MBps, my relay was getting warnings: “Your computer is too slow to handle this many circuit creation requests!”

My CPU is over 80 degrees celsius :o

I tried upgrading from stable to 0.3.2.7-rc, but that didn't help the temperature or CPU usage. Not sure if the circuit warnings are gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

I may have just been mistaken about my bandwidth and CPU usage before. I was trying to just eyeball the Nyx graph, but I should've been reading the actual average it gives me. My avg download is 1.5 MBps and avg upload is 1.4 MBps. This may be normal for a Raspberry Pi 3 while it's being CPU throttled for overheating (the CPU is always 80-83 degrees C).